# How to remove customer account validation in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

While creating an account , I want remove **"email already exist validation"** from **CreatePost.php** file

```
Path: \vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\createpost.php
```

Comment: why you want to  remove this 'email already exist validation` validation

Comment: actually , i want to provide functionality like "customer can create account as supplier  with same email id " and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Please don't do that, Email address should be unique, if you do that you will end up with multiple users with the same email address, you thought a little if you ever want to **load user by email** ? something like this:

```
Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface

public function get($email, $websiteId = null);
```

Or with the object manager (not recommended but just for the exemple):

```
$CustomerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$CustomerModel->setWebsiteId(1);
$CustomerModel->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
$userId = $CustomerModel->getId();
```

I think you have the answer.

**Update:**

Path : `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php::execute()`

```
} catch (StateException $e) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
            $message = __(
                'There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%1">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.',
                $url
            );
            // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            $this->messageManager->addError($message);
```

**Important:**  It's just to show you the piece of code, if you want to change the behavior of your Magento go ahead it's your responsibility and don't change it in this path, you have to rewrite it in a`pp/code/...`

Comment: but where should i put this

Comment: No, you should put it anywhere, just to show that if you do that (remove email already exist validation), it will cause you problems later.

Comment: okay , can you  show me?  Where the code of validation ?

Comment: Look my update.